# Change markup shown before the search result

Tags: theming, 8, search

How do I change this markup from my .theme file?

Line 119 and following in core/modules/search/src/Controller/SearchController.php contain this code.

```
if (count($results)) {
  $build['search_results_title'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<h2>' . $this->t('Search results') . '</h2>',
  );
}
```

I want to remove the `<h2>` tags from my search page.

I am able to change the search form above, and the result list after that tag using 
`hook_preprocess_form()`on the search form and `hook_preprocess_search_result()` on the search results.

Is there a preprocess function I am missing, or can I use a custom template?

Answer (score 2):

This answer has already been answered on [Core search module, change markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625840/drupal-8-core-search-module-change-markup). This is what the accepted answer for that question says.

> You have to alter the route defined by the search module.
> In order to do so:
>
> 1. Define in your `mymodule.services.yml` file following:
>
> ```yaml
> services:
>   mymodule.route_subscriber:
>     class: Drupal\mymodule\Routing\RouteSubscriber
>     tags:
>       - { name: event_subscriber }
> ```
>
> 2. Create a class that extends the `RouteSubscriberBase` class on /mymodule/src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php as following:
>
> ````php
> /**
>  * @file
>  * Contains \Drupal\mymodule\Routing\RouteSubscriber.
>  */
>    
> namespace Drupal\mymodule\Routing;
>   
> use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
> use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
>   
> /**
>  * Listens to the dynamic route events.
>  */
> class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {
>    
>   /**
>    * {@inheritdoc}
>    */
>   public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
>     // Replace dynamically created "search.view_node_search" route's Controller
>     // with our own.
>     if ($route = $collection->get('search.view_node_search')) {
>       $route->setDefault('_controller', '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleSearchController::view');
>     }
>   }
>
> }
>
> 3. Finally, the controller itself located on /mymodule/src/Controller/MyModuleSearchController.php
>
> ```php
> namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;
>  
> use Drupal\search\SearchPageInterface;
> use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
> use Drupal\search\Controller\SearchController;
>   
> /**
>  * Override the Route controller for search.
>  */
> class MyModuleSearchController extends SearchController {
>   
>   /**
>    * {@inheritdoc}
>    */
>   public function view(Request $request, SearchPageInterface $entity) {
>     $build = parent::view($request, $entity);
>     // Unset the Result title.
>     if (isset($build['search_results_title'])) {
>       unset($build['search_results_title']);
>     }
>   
>     return $build;
>   }
>   
> }
> ````

Comment: JFK: Thank you so much! You saved me many hours

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem wherein i had to hide the Search Results H2 tag entirely.

I could manage to do it with Jquery with the below code :

```
$('h2:contains("Search results")').css("display", "none");
```